# How do I fix an unterminated string constant?

Tags: asp.net, html

This is the error I get  :  It only happens when I hit save to try to save a contact.

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BOIE8;ENUSMSCOM)
Timestamp: Tue, 27 Dec 2011 18:17:25 UTC


Message: Unterminated string constant
Line: 8
Char: 296
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/bweb/orders/order_new_b.aspx
```

this is line is lines 5-16

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="user_controls" TagName="bulk_dump" Src="/BWeb/user_controls/uc_bulk_import.ascx" %>

<HTML>
  <HEAD>   ***Line 8 is here***
<title></title>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=stylesheet%>">
<script language="javascript" src="/modules/page_utils.js"></script>
<%=err_message%>
<script language="javascript">
<!--

function rem
```

Comment: It is more likely the error is in the way you are saving data or the data itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the analyst look at it and he told me that the dev area where i was working in is missing to many sql tables for this to work thus I am now doing it in production and it is working perfectly. Sometimes I wish they would tell us these things before assigning a project like this

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely you are having an error in line 10 or line 12, which are actually where you have your asp tags opened (I can see a syntax error in line 10 `href="<%=stylesheet%>">` <-- extra ">" character) In the meanwhile I would suggest to replace your asp tags with the actual values until you figure the error out.

Comment: I had the analyst look at it and he told me that the dev area where i was working in is missing to many sql tables for this to work thus I am now doing it in production and it is working perfectly.  Sometimes I wish they would tell us these things before assigning a project like this.